# Repetitive element after xsd:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I have XML with some elements, which don't have strict order and after that I have notes, which can be multiple:

```
<xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="name" />
            <xs:element name="surname" />
            <xs:element name="birthday" />
            <xs:element name="placeOfBirth" />
        </xs:all>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="note" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there an alternative to the incorrect `xs:complexType` shown above?

**Edit:** As valid I want any order of `name`/`surname`/`birthday`/`placeOfBirth` followed by any number of `note` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to be able to follow an `xs:all` with multiple elements like that.

If you're willing to let the multiple `note` elements appear anywhere in the ordering, and you're willing to wrap it in a container element, you could do the following:

```
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" />
        <xs:element name="surname" />
        <xs:element name="birthday" />
        <xs:element name="placeOfBirth" />
        <xs:element name="notes">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="note" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Or, if you're willing to wrap the unordered parts in a, say, `info` element, this would work:

```
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="info">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="name" />
              <xs:element name="surname" />
              <xs:element name="birthday" />
              <xs:element name="placeOfBirth" />
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="note" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Really, though, I'd drop the unordered constraint:

```
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" />
        <xs:element name="surname" />
        <xs:element name="birthday" />
        <xs:element name="placeOfBirth" />
        <xs:element name="note" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The flexibility of having elements in different order tends not to be that useful in practice and can create confining issues such as this as a schema evolves.

Comment: I added another possibility for you: Wrap the unordered parts in an `info` container element, then you can follow `info` with multiple `note` elements.

Comment: I have existing XML files and I make XSD to them. There is no wrapper I'm affraid.

Answer (score 1):

kjhughes has already given a good survey of options.  Two others may be worth mentioning:

- In XSD 1.1, allow `note` to occur anywhere, not just at the end:

  ```
  <xsd:all
    <xsd:element ref="name"/>
    <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
    <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
    <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
    <xsd:element ref="note" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:all>
  ```
- For a design that is not particularly pretty or clean, there is no need for a content model which is pretty or clean.  Embrace ugliness.  Grind out the 24 permutations of name, surname, birthday, and placeofbirth and write the content model to accept them.

  ```
  <xsd:choice><xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="name"/>
    <xsd:choice><xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
      <xsd:choice><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
        <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
        </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
        <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
      </xsd:sequence></xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
      <xsd:choice><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
        <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
        </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
        <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
      </xsd:sequence></xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
      <xsd:choice><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
        <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
        </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
        <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
      </xsd:sequence></xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence></xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="surname"/>
    <xsd:choice> ...</xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="birthday"/>
    <xsd:choice> ...</xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence><xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="placeofbirth"/>
    <xsd:choice> ...</xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence></xsd:choice>
  ```
- Validate the document by (a) transforming it to a related form which is more easily validated and (b) validating against the schema for that form.  (If the existing format is imposed by a higher authority, of course, they may regard this approach as a criticism of the format; you will need to decide whether that's a dangerous risk to take.)